# getting error : Field passengerInfoRepository in FlightBookingService required a bean of type '.PassengerInfoRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

There is not getting bean type of repository

/*

```
Description:

Field passengerInfoRepository in paymentgateway.service.FlightBookingService required a bean of type 'paymentgateway.repository.PassengerInfoRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'paymentgateway.repository.PassengerInfoRepository' in your configuration.
```

**/

application main method

/**

```
package paymentgateway;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import paymentgateway.dto.FlightBookingAcknowledgement;
import paymentgateway.dto.FlightBookingRequest;
import paymentgateway.service.FlightBookingService;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@RestController
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PaymentgatewayApplication {

    @Autowired
    private FlightBookingService flightBookingService;
    
    @PostMapping("/bookFlightTicket")
    public FlightBookingAcknowledgement bookFlightTicket(@RequestBody FlightBookingRequest flightBookingRequest) {
        return flightBookingService.bookFlightTicket(flightBookingRequest);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentgatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**/

/**

```
package paymentgateway.service;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import paymentgateway.dto.FlightBookingAcknowledgement;
import paymentgateway.dto.FlightBookingRequest;
import paymentgateway.entity.PassengerInfo;
import paymentgateway.entity.PaymentInfo;
import paymentgateway.repository.PassengerInfoRepository;
import paymentgateway.repository.PaymentInfoRepository;
import paymentgateway.utils.PaymentUtils;

@Service
public class FlightBookingService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PassengerInfoRepository passengerInfoRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PaymentInfoRepository paymentInfoRepository;
    
    @Transactional//(readOnly = false , isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public FlightBookingAcknowledgement bookFlightTicket(FlightBookingRequest flightBookingRequest) {
        
        
        PassengerInfo passengerInfo =  flightBookingRequest.getPassengerInfo();
        
         passengerInfo = passengerInfoRepository.save(passengerInfo);
        
        PaymentInfo paymentInfo = flightBookingRequest.getPaymentInfo();
        
        PaymentUtils.validateCreditLimit(paymentInfo.getAccountNo(), passengerInfo.getFare());
        
        paymentInfo.setAmount(passengerInfo.getFare());
        paymentInfo.setPassengerId(passengerInfo.getPId());
        paymentInfoRepository.save(paymentInfo);
        
        return new FlightBookingAcknowledgement("success", passengerInfo.getFare(),UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0],passengerInfo);
        
    }

}
```

**/

repository.java

/**

package paymentgateway.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import paymentgateway.entity.PaymentInfo;

public interface PaymentInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentInfo, String>{

}

**/

package paymentgateway.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import paymentgateway.entity.PassengerInfo;

public interface PassengerInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<PassengerInfo, Long> {

}

/**

**/

Comment: i made so many mistakes in my question please correct it please dont dislike ... please correct it please

Comment: help me not getting bean type

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain a `DataSource` bean, nor is Spring providing any because you're excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`. This is a problem, because the [`JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html) autoconfiguration is only invoked when a `DataSource` bean is present (it has a `@ConditionalOnBean`).

The easiest solution is to re-enable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` by removing the exclusion:

```java
@SpringBootApplication // Remove the `exclude` here
@RestController
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PaymentgatewayApplication {
    // ...
}
```

After that, you can configure a `DataSource` bean with the `spring.datasource.*` properties and by providing the proper JDBC driver on your classpath.

Comment: how to use spring datasource in properties file

Comment: @Muhammadsaied You add a `spring.datasource.url` property containing the JDBC URL of the database and a `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` property if there's any authentication necessary. How you fill it depends on what type of database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, you need to remove the **exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}** line from your **@SpringBootApplication** annotation. This exclusion prevents Spring Boot from automatically configuring a data source based on your application's properties. By removing this, Spring Boot will be able to auto-configure the data source using the properties defined in your application. This allows the necessary bean for **PassengerInfoRepository** to be created and properly injected into the **FlightBookingService**.
Additionally, ensure that you have added the **@Repository** annotation to your **PassengerInfoRepository** interface. This annotation informs Spring that the interface is a repository and allows the creation of the necessary bean.

Comment: The `@Repository` annotation is not necessary if a repository extends from `JpaRepository`.